# Visualizing predicted probabilities from logistic regression with a weighted sample in Stata

Tags: data-visualization, logistic, stata, weighted-sampling

I was using the `predxcon` command to graph the predicted probabilities for logistic regression. Basically I want to see the pattern for predicted probabilities of the outcome by each age group. Using `predxcon` command, it provided the graph, as well as corresponding values.

However, I realized that the sample is weighted and I need to use `svy` to adjust for the weights. I am wondering if there is any program like `predxcon` when using `svy`?

I am planning to calculate the predicted probabilities based on coefficients provided by the regression result with adjustment by the weights. Is there anything I should be aware of, since this is `svy`? Do I need to consider weights or I can just use the coefficients for each predictor?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `predxcon` is not a standard Stata command. It is a user-written command. This command does not allow to take into account weights or survey sampling designs. However, it is not too hard to knit something by yourself. Here is a simple example that you can customize and adapt to your needs:

```
// Use some survey data available on the web
webuse nhanes2d, clear

// Declare the survey design
svyset psu [pw = finalwgt]

// Estimate a logit model and compute the predicted probabilities
svy: logit highbp weight
predict phat, p

// Generate the grid to evaluate the predicted probabilities
// [30, 40[  [40, 50[ ... 
gen wgtcl = floor(weight/10) * 10

// List the results
tabstat phat, s(mean) by(wgtcl) nototal

// List and graph the results
preserve
collapse (mean) phat, by(wgtcl)
list, sep(0) noobs 
tw con phat wgtcl
restore
```